# Can't use any DLC red text content for Borderlands 2

Tags: borderlands-2

I cant seem to use any DLC redtext weaponry, even after completing Captain Scarlet's campaign. At the top of a weapon pane, it still reads "requires pirate booty", of which I happily looted previously.

Comment: This situation should not exist and is a bug. What platform are you on?

Comment: 360 dude, i am going to delete the download and reload from the expansion disc, i am wary of losing charcter data as i might even have to re install the original game as well, no x box live means i dont have access to patches etc.

Comment: and the same problem for mister torgues campaign as well ( no pick ups for torgue tokens, portraits and red text campaign special items).